# Typo3: GIFBUILDER add distorted text on top of image

Tags: text, typo3, skew

I want to open a blank catalog image and apply on top of it some skewed (distorted) text.
I have this typoscript snippet:

```
/**
* Catalog image
*/
lib.catalogImage = IMAGE
lib.catalogImage {
    file = GIFBUILDER
    file {
        XY = 242,270
        format = png
        quality = 80

        10 = IMAGE
        10 {
            file = EXT:theme/Resources/Public/Images/catalog_blank.jpg
        }

        15 = IMAGE
        15 {
            offset = 20,20

            file = GIFBUILDER
            file {
                XY = 150,50

                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    text = Datenblatt
                    fontSize = 12
                    offset = 28,110
                    fontColor = black
                    niceText = 1
                }

                20 = SCALE
                20 {
                    params = -matte    -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '0,0,0,0  0,90,0,90  90,0,90,25  90,90,90,65'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I always get the text box white, with no text in it.
What am I doing wrong?

Blank catalog image:

[image]

Result image:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I've also tried adding:

```
niceText.after = -matte  -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '0,0,0,0  0,90,0,90  90,0,90,25  90,90,90,65'
```

to the TEXT object, according to the docs (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Gifbuilder/ObjectNames/Index.html), but it doesn't seem to be considered at all. 
The result is this:

[image]

Comment: Just tip: do it with CSS :) https://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/

Comment: In the end, I did, though a text skewed at 7 degrees does not look that good..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like niceText doesn't get along with SCALE.
I removed niceText and the text is now displayed correctly.